# How do I add button on each row in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am newbie for DataTables. I want to add button on each row for edit and delete(like below image)

[image]

I have tried with code:

**Test.cfm**

```html
<table id="myDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>UserID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <th>Passowrd</th>
        <th>Email</th>
         <th>IsActive</th>
         <th>Command</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
</tbody>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
       // "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "fetchUserData.cfm",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": null },
            { "mData": "Name", "sTitle": "Name" , "sWidth": "20%"},
            { "mData": "UserName", "sTitle": "UserName", "sWidth": "20%" },
            { "mData": "Passowrd","sTitle": "Passowrd", "sWidth": "20%"  },
            { "mData": "Email","sTitle": "Email"  , "sWidth": "20%"},
            { "mData": "IsActive","sTitle": "IsActive" , "sWidth": "20%" },
            {
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
               "mRender": function (o) { return '<a href=#/' + o.userid + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>'; }
            }
        ]
    });

} );
```

**fetchUserData.cfm**

```js
{
"aaData": [
    [
        "1",
        "sameek",
        "sam",
        "sam",
        "sameek@test.com",
        "1",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "arun singh",
        "arun",
        "arun",
        "arunsingh@test.com",
        "0",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "9",
        "s s",
        "sam3",
        "sam3",
        "ss@s.com",
        "0",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "10",
        "sameek mishra",
        "sam56",
        "sam",
        "same@s.com",
        "0",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "11",
        "narendra kumar",
        "narendra",
        "nav",
        "sa@sa.com",
        "1",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "12",
        "test test",
        "test",
        "test",
        "test2@test.com",
        "1",
        ""
    ]
]
 }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Basically your code is okay, thats the right way to do this. Anyhow, there are some misunderstandings:

1. fetchUserData.cfm does not contain key/value pairs. So it doesn't make sense to address keys in mData. Just use `mData[index]`
2. dataTables expects some more info from your serverside. At least you should tell datatables how many items in total are on your serverside and how many are filtered.
   I just hardcoded this info to your data. You should get the right values from counts in your server sided script.

   ```
   {
    "iTotalRecords":"6",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords":"6",
     "aaData": [
   [
       "1",
       "sameek",
       "sam",
       "sam",
       "sameek@test.com",
       "1",
       ""
   ],...
   ```
3. If you have the column names already set in the html part, you don't need to add sTitle.
4. The mRender Function takes three parameters:

   - data = The data for this cell, as defined in mData
   - type = The datatype (can be ignored mostly)
   - full = The full data array for this row.

So your mRender function should look like this:

```
  "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
    return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
  }
```

Find a working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JfxeI9Wsr1WnsTiBhhYi?p=preview)

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to add multiple buttons to a single column?

Comment: I actually answered this. What you would do is return an array of each button. `return new array('<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>', '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Delete' + '</a>');`. Of course, the use of new array() is frowned upon (use []), but the idea stands.

Comment: Is it possible to add buttons in the pre-datatables-transformed `<html>`? My page has 6 columns, yet the right-most 2 are static buttons. When I put each of them per row, then use server-side to get an array of JSON objects having 4 key-value pairs, the HTML shows the 2 buttons in the beginning, but then immediately hides them.

Comment: Apologies for late comment... But how do you add `Click` events to that `anchor`tag?

Answer (score 15):

```
var table =$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: yourdata ,
    columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "parent" },
        { data: "date" },

        {data: "id" , render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
              return type === 'display'  ?
                '<a href="<?php echo $delete_url;?>'+ data +'" ><i class="fe fe-delete"></i></a>' :
                data;
            }},
    ],
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering a question, you should provide an explanation along with you solution, rather than just posting code. This will make the answer more useful to the original poster as well as others who may find this question.

Comment: Great, I think this approach makes more sense than others. Yet, I'm experiencing bit trouble attaching a JS function.

Answer (score 14):

take a look here... this was very helpfull to me
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
        "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
    } ]
} );

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    alert( data[0] +"'s salary is: "+ data[ 5 ] );
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

I contribute with my settings for buttons: view, edit and delete.
The last column has data: null
At the end with the property defaultContent is added a string that HTML code. And since it is the last column, it is indicated with index -1 by means of the targets property when indicating the columns.

```
//...
columns: [
    { title: "", "data": null, defaultContent: '' }, //Si pone da error al cambiar de paginas la columna index con numero de fila
    { title: "Id", "data": "id", defaultContent: '', "visible":false },
    { title: "Nombre", "data": "nombre" },
    { title: "Apellido", "data": "apellido" },
    { title: "Documento", "data": "tipo_documento.siglas" },
    { title: "Numero", "data": "numero_documento" },
    { title: "Fec.Nac.", format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', "data": "fecha_nacimiento"}, //formato
    { title: "Teléfono", "data": "telefono1" },
    { title: "Email", "data": "email1" }
    , { title: "", "data": null }
],
columnDefs: [
    {
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0
    },
    { 
      width: '3%', 
      targets: 0  //la primer columna tendra una anchura del  20% de la tabla
    },
    {
        targets: -1, //-1 es la ultima columna y 0 la primera
        data: null,
        defaultContent: '<div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs dt-view" style="margin-right:16px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dt-edit" style="margin-right:16px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dt-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>'
    },
    { orderable: false, searchable: false, targets: -1 } //Ultima columna no ordenable para botones
], 
//...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcQKI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Take a Look.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'ID' },
                { 'data': 'AuthorName' },
                { 'data': 'TotalBook' },
                { 'data': 'DateofBirth' },
                { 'data': 'OccupationEN' },   
                { 'data': null, title: 'Action', wrap: true, "render": function (item) { return '<div class="btn-group"> <button type="button" onclick="set_value(' + item.ID + ')" value="0" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View</button></div>' } },
            ],            
            bServerSide: true,
            sAjaxSource: 'EmployeeDataHandler.ashx'           
        });       
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

my recipe:

datatable declaration:

```
defaultContent: "<button type='button'....
```

events:

```
$('#usersDataTable tbody').on( 'click', '.delete-user-btn', function () { var user_data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i just added `button` in data.
For Example, 
i should code like this:

```
$(target).DataTable().row.add(message).draw()
```

And, in `message`, i added button like this : `[blah, blah ... "<button>Click!</button>"]` and.. it works!