# Add a button to open pop up in jQuery Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, popup

In my app, I used jQuery Data Table to show the results of a query made by form. I have now a new task: I must add, in this table, a column where for each row I have a button (or a link, no matter which of this 2).

The focal point is that when a user click this button or link, a popup must be open to allow the operator to modify some value in the db (so it's for this that I need a button for each row; every row may have a value to modify, or not).

The question is: how can I add this button/link and how can I force, after click, the popup opening?

Comment: Show your code here please

Comment: Use bootstrap modal

Comment: Adding buttons to each row in datatables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-to-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
$('#data_table').DataTable( {
  data: data
});

$(document).on('click', '#data_table tbody tr', function(){
  // alert('hello');
  $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/46/)

**Note:** In this example I am using `jquery ui dialog`, you can use `Bootstrap modal` as well

Comment: Enjoy weekend!!

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap Modal. Bootstrap modal will allow you to do the operation you want