# How do I add a button on each row in DataTable when using SQL connection

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, datatable

I am brand new to using DataTables and trying to add a button to the end of a row that passes a value to a function to insert into another sql database table. I'm using an SQL connection and have not implemented AJAX yet.

[Was following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-do-i-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable)

**My ASPX File is using this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#invSearch').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
            } ]
        } );

        $('#invSearch tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
            alert( data[0] +"'s name is: "+ data[ 2 ] );
        } );
    } );

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#invSearch tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#invSearch').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

**My table is created in the C# file using this code:**

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    SqlDataReader user = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    String UnreadText = "";
    Int32 i = 0;
    while (user.Read())
    {
        UnreadText += "         <td class=\"left\">" + user["id"] + "</td>";
        UnreadText += "         <td class=\"left\">" + user["name"] + "</td>";
        UnreadText += "         <td class=\"left\">" + user["country_long"] + "</td>";
        UnreadText += "         <td class=\"center\">";
        UnreadText += "             <a class=\"btn btn-info\" href=\"#\" runat=\"server\" onServerClick=\"AddProspect_Click\" />";
        UnreadText += "                 <i class=\"icon-edit icon-white\"></i>  ";
        UnreadText += "                 Add                                    ";
        UnreadText += "             </a>";
        UnreadText += "             <a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"#\" runat=\"server\" onServerClick=\"DelProspect_Click\" />";
        UnreadText += "                 <i class=\"icon-edit icon-white\"></i>  ";
        UnreadText += "                 Delete                                    ";
        UnreadText += "             </a>";
        UnreadText += "         </td>";
        UnreadText += "     </tr>";
        tlist.InnerHtml = UnreadText;
        i++;
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the "id" column to pass to my "AddProspect_Click" function in C#.

Comment: you need to use grid view

Comment: I chose this datatable example due to its search/sort/etc. is there no way to add a button in the above example and pass a value to a c# function?

Comment: Read about [Separation of concerns.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: put the id in to the link itself using data attribute it could be as follows : `<a class=\"btn btn-info\" data-id=\"" + user["id"] + "\"`, then get it from within the click method

Comment: for some reason my button click is not calling the function... not sure how to resolve that.