# I want to add edit and delete buttons in datatables using codenigator

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to add edit and delete buttons in datatables using codenigator . This is my controller code where i am displaying the data. Now i want to add buttons but can made the logic that how to print those buttons. I am using codeginator

```
public function dataa()
    {
        $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
          $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
          $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
          $this->load->model('mymodel');
          $this->load->library('Datatables');
          $this->Datatables->add_column('edit','<a href="#">edit</a>');


          $record = $this->mymodel->records();

          $data = array();

          foreach($record->result() as $r) {

               $data[] = array(
                    $r->email,
                    $r->name,
                    $r->fathername,
                    $r->phone 
               );
          }

          $output = array(
               "draw" => $draw,
                 "recordsTotal" => $record->num_rows(),
                 "recordsFiltered" => $record->num_rows(),
                 "data" => $data

            );
          echo json_encode($output);
          exit();
    }
```

and this is my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#record-table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo site_url("mycontroller/dataa") ?>",
            type : 'GET'
        },

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not that what i want i am using codeigator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add button on each row in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-do-i-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: no thats not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try this in your code:

```
foreach($record->result() as $r) {

           $data[] = array(
                $r->email,
                $r->name,
                $r->fathername,
                $r->phone ,
                "<a href='#'>edit</a>"

           );
      }
```

Comment: gives me that error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be useful

in your Controller

```
if (!empty($record->result())) {
        foreach ($record->result() as $r) {
            $nestedData['email'] = $r->emailemail;
            $nestedData['name'] = $r->name;
            $nestedData['fathername'] = $r->fathername;
            $nestedData['phone'] = $r->phone;
            $nestedData['action'] = "<a href='#'></a>";

            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "draw" => intval($this->input->post('draw')),
        "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data" => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
```

and in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#record-table').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url : "<?php echo site_url("mycontroller/dataa") ?>",
                type : 'POST'
            },
            columns: [
                        {data: "email"},
                        {data: "name"},
                        {data: "fathername"},
                        {data: "phone"},
                        {data: "action"},
                    ],

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Its not loading my data

Comment: Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at getWebspeed (chrome-extension://pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh/webspeed.js:83:72)
    at Object.chrome.storage.local.get [as callback] (chrome-extension://pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh/webspeed.js:95:31)
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://pgjjikdiikihdfpoppgaidccahalehjh/webspeed.js:94:29)
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://ziksoft.com/task2/mycontroller/dataa 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your table for your edit and delete button. (ex. action column).
just match the number of columns to the number of data inside your `$data` variable

```
$data = array();

          foreach($record->result() as $r) {

               $data[] = array(
                    $r->email,
                    $r->name,
                    $r->fathername,
                    $r->phone,
                    '<a href="#">edit</a>',
                    '<a href="#">delete</a>'
               );
          }
```

Comment: @QadeerMalik If you are using google chrome as browser, you can check developer tools. Go to network tab. refresh your page first then try to load the page where the datatable should be load. It will show the error/response

Comment: try to remove this line`$this->Datatables->add_column('edit','<a href="#">edit</a>');` , Have you add another column for your `edit` and `delete` button?. just like for email,name, etc

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=record-table - Requested unknown parameter 'email' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

you can add helper database_helper

```
function callback_delete($id)
{
   return "<button class='btn btn-danger delete' data-
           id='{$id}'>Delete</button>";
}

function callback_edit($id)
{
    return "<button class='btn btn-primary edit' data-id='{$id}' data-
           toggle='modal' data-target='#editInsertmodal'>Edit</button> 
           ";
}
```

and call like this in controller

```
public function get_user()
{
    $this->load->helper('database');
    $this->datatables-
>select('user_id,user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email')
        ->from('users')
        ->add_column('Edit','$1','callback_edit(user_id)')
        ->add_column('Delete','$1','callback_delete(user_id)');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```