# Adding buttons to a datatable page

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-5

I've made a datatable and want the last column to have 1-2 buttons ?
If it's possible , the code should be able to read a column value and set the button based on that.

This is my html of the table

```
<div class="container text-nowrap " >
          <h1 class="text-center">Ideas</h1>
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered mb-0 " id="newideastable">
            <thead >
              <tr class="text-center" >
                <th  style="background-color: #009879;">No.</th>
                <th>Title</th>

                ....... other rows

                <th>Published Date</th>
                <th style="background-color: #009879;">Options</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery for it

```
let table = new DataTable('#newideastable', {
    scroller: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: false,
    pagingType: "full",
    fixedColumns: {
          left: 1,
          right: 1
      },
    "language": {
          "paginate": {
                  page: 'Page %d',
                  pageOf: 'of %d',
                  info: 'Displaying records %d - %d of %d',
                  infoEmpty: 'No records to display',
                  infoFiltered: '(filtered from %d total records)',
            }
      },
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/ideas",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataType": "json"
      },
      
      "columns": [
        { "data": "idea_number" },
        ...... other data
        { "data": "date" }
      ],
      "createdRow": (row, data, dataIndex) => {
            $(row).addClass("table-info");
            $(row).on('click', function() {
                setideamodal(data.idea_number);// sets a pop up bootstrap modal
            });
      }
    // options
  });
```

For now what I'm doing is setting the button with defaultContent(https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) and then using another function right after the ajax call to iterate through each of them and set the buttons.

It does work that way but I am technically avoiding the problem . Can I do this inside the ajax call and if possible using the same column's data value?

Comment: Related: [How do I add button on each row in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22471862/12567365), and similar questions on Stack Overflow, with some different ways to solve this.

Comment: @andrewJames so in my case it will be for the last column `{
    "Data": null,
   "Render": function () {  
    if (Data.<lastcolname>== value ) 
    { return '<button //some attribues > Action</button><button>//another button'; } 
    return 'No action possible' 
    }

}`
I mean basically I use `Data.<lastcolname>` in that function assigned to `Render`  to access that col value right?